# handling button events from servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, button

I have a jsp page that contain a button when the user click on the button i want to display a text 
so any idea how to handle the onClick event from JSP

Thank you in advance

Comment: The text that you want to display, will it come from the server.

Comment: here's my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362638/error-404-servlet-not-found-with-tomcat

Comment: why can't you use HTML/Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
<div id='myDiv'></div>

<input id='myButton' type='button' value='My Button' />

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myButton').click(function()
{

$("#myDiv").html("The text that you want to display");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is *no* such event system in `servlet/JSP`. In fact you may pass *key-value* pair data along with the servlet request.

sample.jsp

```
<form method="post" action="servlet_url">
  <input type="submit" name="cmd" value="Add"/>
  <input type="submit" name="cmd" value="Delete"/>
</form>
```

and code in `doPost` of servlet

```
String cmd=request.getParameter("cmd");
if(cmd.equals("Add"))
  {
   //
  }
else
if(cmd.equals("Delete"))
 {
 //
 }
```